# Simultaneous many-shape rotation between fixed positions on Powerpoint

Tags: vba, textbox, powerpoint

I have six objects, all in a given fixed position, as depicted below

[image]

The text boxes all have the same size. I would like to automate the counterclockwise rotation of all text boxes, so that when I use the macro, it will rotate the text 60º ccw (thus BETA becomes ALPHA, ALPHA becomes ZETA and so forth). However, I'm completely clueless on how to write it in VBA! I know that I can set the textbox using

```
Set myDocument = ActivePresentation.Slides(1) 
myDocument.Shapes.AddTextbox(Type:=msoTextOrientationHorizontal, _ 
    Left:=400, Top:=100, Width:=160, Height:=30).TextFrame _ 
    .TextRange.Text = "ALPHA"
```

But, I'm clueless on how to rotate them. Another alternative would be to create these six TextBoxes and create a function that only changed the text variable, but my VBA knowledge is very elementary, and I wouldn't even know where to begin :\

Can anyone be so kind as to give me a small help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean to rotate their position and not their orientation it could look like this:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub ExampleRotatePositions()
    Dim myDocument As Slide
    Set myDocument = ActivePresentation.Slides(1)

    Dim TextBox(1 To 6) As Shape

    'create the textboxes in your desired position.
    Set TextBox(1) = myDocument.Shapes.AddTextbox(Orientation:=msoTextOrientationHorizontal, Left:=100, Top:=100, Width:=160, Height:=30)
    TextBox(1).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "ALPHA"

    Set TextBox(2) = myDocument.Shapes.AddTextbox(Orientation:=msoTextOrientationHorizontal, Left:=200, Top:=100, Width:=160, Height:=30)
    TextBox(2).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "BETA"

    Set TextBox(3) = myDocument.Shapes.AddTextbox(Orientation:=msoTextOrientationHorizontal, Left:=300, Top:=100, Width:=160, Height:=30)
    TextBox(3).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "GAMMA"

    Set TextBox(4) = myDocument.Shapes.AddTextbox(Orientation:=msoTextOrientationHorizontal, Left:=400, Top:=100, Width:=160, Height:=30)
    TextBox(4).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "DELTA"

    Set TextBox(5) = myDocument.Shapes.AddTextbox(Orientation:=msoTextOrientationHorizontal, Left:=500, Top:=100, Width:=160, Height:=30)
    TextBox(5).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "EPSILON"

    Set TextBox(6) = myDocument.Shapes.AddTextbox(Orientation:=msoTextOrientationHorizontal, Left:=600, Top:=100, Width:=160, Height:=30)
    TextBox(6).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "ZETA"

    MsgBox "Start rotating now"


    'remember last position
    Dim LastLeft As Single
    LastLeft = TextBox(UBound(TextBox)).Left
    Dim LastTop As Single
    LastTop = TextBox(UBound(TextBox)).Top

    'rotate position
    Dim iTextBox As Long
    For iTextBox = UBound(TextBox) - 1 To LBound(TextBox) Step -1
        TextBox(iTextBox + 1).Left = TextBox(iTextBox).Left
        TextBox(iTextBox + 1).Top = TextBox(iTextBox).Top
    Next iTextBox

    'move first to last position
    TextBox(LBound(TextBox)).Left = LastLeft
    TextBox(LBound(TextBox)).Top = LastTop
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Group them using the [ShapeRange.Group method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.shaperange.group) and then rotate the group:

```
Set myDocument = ActivePresentation.Slides(1)

With myDocument.Shapes   
    .AddShape(msoShapeCan, 50, 10, 100, 200).Name = "shpOne"
    .AddShape(msoShapeCube, 150, 250, 100, 200).Name = "shpTwo"

    With .Range(Array("shpOne", "shpTwo")).Group
        .Fill.PresetTextured msoTextureBlueTissuePaper
        .Rotation = 45
        .ZOrder msoSendToBack
    End With
End With
```

Comment: It won't work, since you'll be considering the whole group to rotate (that is, the shapes are fixed within the frame of the group). In the end, you'll get the objects in different positions, yes, but not respecting the original orientation. Also, the code doesn't allow further rotation of the objects...

Comment: @Strelok Well your question wasn't clear. You don't mean rotate (in the meaning of orientation) but in the meaning of rotating position. I wrote another anwer for that.